# Trying to write a Pig Latin program in C++, I cannot get the individual words of my string into a cstring to be able to edit

Tags: c++

The program is supposed to read in a line of a file, then cout the english version of the statement and then the pig latin version of it. then continue until the file is finished.

The trouble i am having i think is i cannot figure out how to input each word of the string into the cstring to edit it.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("ASSGN8-A.txt");
    char myCString[12], pigLatin[12];
    string myString;
    char letter;
    bool eof = false;

    do
    {
        std::getline(inFile, myString);
        cout << "English: " << myString << endl;
        cout << "Pig Latin: ";
        if (myString == "\0")
        {
            myCString = myString;
            letter = myCString[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                pigLatin[i] = myCString[i+1];
            }
            cout << pigLatin << "ay";

        }
        if(inFile.eof())
        {
            eof = true;
        }
    }while (!eof);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a cstring to edit?

Comment: unrelated: `if(inFile.eof())` what if you have an IO error and never hit the end of the stream? Setting yourself up for an infinite loop there. `while(std::getline(inFile, myString))` is a much safer option than what you currently have with the `do`/`while`

Comment: `myCString = myString;` is an awesomely bad idea and does not seem necessary. Just use the `string` and its `[]` overload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method below to split the string into words:

```
vector<string> words;
istringstream n(myString);
string word;
while(getline(n, word, ' ')) words.push_back(word);
```

Comment: `vector` is wasteful overkill here.  When you see a word, just process and print it.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok it is just a generic example.